# What are padding `valid` in Keras Conv2D and how to disable padding?

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network

It is [said in docs](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#conv2d), that padding argument for Conv2D can be `same` or `valid`. What is `same` is clear? But what is `valid`? How to disable padding at all?